# Renting a car - Slovakia

Tags: car-rentals, poland, krakow, slovakia

I'm planning to rent a car within 4 friends in Poland and drive down to Slovakia, I [read](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g274772-i961-k7650411-Day_Trip_by_Rental_Car_from_Krakow_to_Slovakia-Krakow_Lesser_Poland_Province_Southern_Poland.html) that I've to buy one sticker to drive on highways. Is this still applies? How can I get them?

Comment: Hi. We're not really a general advice forum. We answer specific questions. Is there a specific concern you have?

Comment: Good points, thanks. I clarified the question on the last edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any stickers in Poland, but you do need them in Slovakia, you can buy them at gas stations in SK.

http://www.slovakia.com/travel/car/

Comment: Even if I don't take any highways?

Comment: @Custodio No, you do not need stickers (Highway Toll) if you do not drive on highways.